# How do i recover my autolayout constraints after unchecking Autolayout?

Tags: autolayout, ios7, xcode5

I had a scene that took me quite a while to set up in AL.  Originally it was done in iOS6/Xcode4.6 but i migrated it to iOS7/XCode5.

I was fiddling around with moving the navbar and ended up unchecking AL for another scene, the intro scene.  It did what I wanted with the intro scene but when I went back to the detail scene which is where i had a lot of work done with AL constraints, I noticed that now when I select it and go to the dimensions inspector, all layouts and guides are gone.

Is this because i migrated from ios6 or because i unchecked AL?

Can I get them back?

Comment: This is obviously not the answer you want to hear, but this is a perfect example of why you should be using version control (such as git, which is integrated into Xcode) so that you can always manage changes and revert file(s) back to a previous state when needed.

Comment: I dont mind so much that its not the answer i want to hear.  Its just that Im trying to fix the issue so I checked AL again but my controls (buttons & labels) dont show the typical AL yellow bounding boxes and blue bar constraints.

Comment: I just unchecked autolayout for a specific view to realize it undid all constraints for my whole project. I also don't know how to get them back. I'm gonna have to revert to my last commit in git which was a while back. Damn it.

Comment: This should definitely have had a warning "Do you really want to remove all the storyboard constraints?" Oh well...